# Две СУБД на 1 сервере?

Tags: mysql, веб-сервер

Я еще совсем новичек в бэкенде, поэтому и не могу понять:
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀   ⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀    **Как две СУБД: MySQL и MariaDB работают на одном сервере?**

Или MariaDB это база данных, а MySQL управляет ей?
⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀    ⠀⠀⠀     ⠀⠀ Я совсем запутался, я чего-то не понимаю =(

Вот скрин, где я пометил красным маркером:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю, здесь имеется в виду, что MariaDB — это СУБД совместимая с MySQL, а запущена она всего одна

Comment: Тем не менее, теоретически нет никаких ограничений на число запущенных СУБД — хоть две, хоть десять, хоть миллион (лишь бы памяти хватило)

Comment: Так у меня запущены сразу две СУБД?

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Одной СУБД недостаточно?

Comment: Как я уже написал в первом комментарии — запущена она всего одна (скорее всего)

Comment: Она это MariaDb или Mysql?

Comment: Строка «Версия сервера» намекает, что всё-таки MariaDB (причём очень-очень старая версия)

Comment: Первая строка: Говорит что сервер: MySql, а третья строка: что сервер MariaDB. Во путаница.

Comment: Ну про путаницу это уже спрашивайте у тех, кто написал такой запутывающий текст

Comment: Так это было написано в phpmyadmin. Разве весь этот текст пишет человек? Вроде же программа сама автоматом показывает версии.

Comment: А где обновлять MariaDb? Нужно обратиться к хостингу?

Comment: По моему текст совершенно понятный. Сервер MySQL, а его более точный тип MariaDB. Это примерно как версия. С изначальной БД MySQL сейчас сделали несколько форков, это та же mysql но с доработками от различных команд разработчиков. Среди них самые известные это MariaDB и Percona. Хотя чистая MySQL осталась, та что сейчас дорабатывается Oracle co

Comment: Как я понимаю MariaDB это улучшенная версия MySQL?

Comment: Уже ответил на https://qna.habr.com/q/1123276 - повторять лень.

Comment: *Как я понимаю MariaDB это улучшенная версия MySQL?* Неправильно понимаете. Не лучше, не хуже - просто другая. С другим (хотя и во многом общим) набором возможностей.

Comment: А где обновлять MariaDb? Нужно обратиться к хостингу?